# Problem with ATmega328P when used with DRV8302 gate driver

Tags: atmega, motor-controller, texas-instruments, gate-driving, atmega328p

I am developing a motor controller for a 48V BLDC motor. For this, I am using the ATmega328P microcontroller in combination with the DRV8302 gate driver from Texas Instruments. It uses a simple control algorithm, wherein it gets an input from the throttle and outputs a PWM signal with a duty cycle proportional to the throttle to the input pins of the gate driver, which in turn outputs a signal to turn on the MOSFETs corresponding to the phase that is to be energized. While testing this circuit on a breadboard, I found that the PWM outputs of the microcontroller work well independently, but on giving +5V to the EN_GATE pin of the gate driver, the microcontroller shuts down and ceases to give the PWM output. A schematic of my circuit is given below. Why is this happening and what is a resolution?
[image: Microcontroller Circuit schematic]  [image: Gate driver circuit schematic]

Comment: Have you taken a look at VCC with a scope yet?  You may be inducing noise or even brown out when you actually start driving the motor.  When the uC "shuts down", how are you noticing that (ie, does only the PWM signal stop, or is there additional evidence that the uC has completely shut down?)

Comment: You can use internal buck regulator (EN_BUCK) for providing enough power for the DRV.

Comment: The clock circuit, made with the crystal and caps, is very susceptible to stop working - if overloaded or does not get enough voltage.  I recommend a separate clock oscillator module, or isolate your clock via an amplifier.